# Timing display of Graphics (Front End timing)

Tags: graphics, front-end, performance-tuning

I want to know how much wall-time it takes to display a `Graphics`

For example this one:

```
ballGrid[n_] := Module[{lines},
  lines = Line[Flatten[Table[{
       {{i, j, 0}, {i, j, 1}},
       {{i, 0, j}, {i, 1, j}},
       {{0, i, j}, {1, i, j}}},
      {i, 0, 1, 1/n}, {j, 0, 1, 1/n}], 2]];
  Graphics3D[{Sphere[Tuples[Range[0, 1, 1/n], 3], 1/(10 n)], lines}, 
   Boxed -> False]]
```

First of all note that running `ballGrid[50]` and `ballGrid[50];` takes significantly different wall time to run

Just using `AbsoluteTiming` does not give accurate representation (I assume it only measures kernel time):

```
In[]:= AbsoluteTiming[ballGrid[50];]
In[]:= AbsoluteTiming[ballGrid[50]]
Out[]:= {0.082963,Null}
Out[]:= {0.029378,<<Graphics>>}
```

I answered my own question, but I'd like to see other solutions too, and know why/if the `Print` workaround can be trusted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From past experimentation (not all of which I remember) here are several things that contribute to the time it takes to display graphics, including:

- converting the `Graphics` expression to boxes (in the kernel)
- compressing the result if it's very large (if you examine large graphics cells, you'll notice that they're compressed)
- transferring the (possibly compressed) box expression to the Front End through MathLink
- rendering the graphics

I played with these a little bit in the past, trying to figure out what contributes the most to the timing.  Unfortunately I don't remember all the details (and I won't have time to do all the tests again now), but I do know that: 1. converting to boxes might take longer than the rendering itself in some cases 2. compression may take measurable time too.

If you want to measure the full time needed to display a `Graphics`, then I recommend something like

```
s = AbsoluteTime[];

ballGrid[30]

AbsoluteTime[] - s
```

In order or this to give correct results, each command must be in a separate cell.

This gives me **4.9** seconds, which is about the same time I measure with my watch.

The following should be a good approximation to the total display time too, but it'll usually take a little longer to evaluate (**5.1** seconds here):

```
ExportString[ballGrid[30], "BMP"]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

This will measure box generation only (**1.2** seconds):

```
AbsoluteTiming[ToBoxes[ballGrid[30]];]
```

You can add compression on top of that (**1.8** seconds), `AbsoluteTiming[Compress@ToBoxes[ballGrid[30]];]`, but I'm not sure that the same compression method implemented in `Compress` is used when sending the data to the FE.

Your method (`AbsoluteTiming[Print@ballGrid[30]]`) should include at least box generation and compression, and possibly MathLink transfer too (just a guess, I'm not sure about this last one).  It gives **2.0** seconds on my machine, but I can measure 5 seconds with a watch before I actually see the graphics.

I hope this answer will help you in digging deeper into what happens exactly when graphics are displayed and how to time the process correctly ... I simply wanted to point out that doing this is not quite as straightforward as it might seem at first.

Comment: Please see [this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3365271#3365271) too. Sometimes you can convert the `Graphics` to boxes yourself, speeding up the process considerably.

Comment: Related discussion: https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2327797

Answer (score 1):

I typically execute `t=AbsoluteTime[]` immediately before execution of the graphics command (in the same cell, even) and then execute `AbsoluteTime[]-t` in the cell immediately after.  It's important that you select and enter both `Input` cells simultaneously - as the cells are selected in the image below.

[image]

Comment: That gave me 2s extra compared to the `Print` workaround, and that agrees with true time.
How come they have to be on different input cells? Does that force Mathematica to render the output before giving the next input to the kernel?

Comment: @ssch I believe that's essentially correct. Rendering is done in the front end. Once a `Graphics` expression is sent to the front end, the kernel can get to work on input in the current cell, but not the next cell.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is to use `Print`

```
In[]:= AbsoluteTiming[Print[ballGrid[50]];]
<<Graphics>>
Out[]:= {14.438180, Null}
```

Comment: I *think* this will time formatting the graphics expression (converting to boxes), but it will not time rendering.  Depending on what sort of graphics you are displaying, both operations might take a significant time.